How to get output of lua function in command line
I have the following lua function:
function GET_STRING()
  return "THE_STRING"
end

I want to press : to enter command mode and execute the lua function so the final command looks like :THE_STRING. Context: I want to create a keybinding which automatically creates this command.

Did you see https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua-guide.html#lua-guide-using-Lua already?

Yes, my question is not about how to execute a lua function as a command (I don't want to do :lua GET_STRING()). I want to execute the lua function to get :THE_STRING.

Okay, so your question is something like "how to execute command given its name as a string".

Sorry this is somewhat hard to explain. I want to enter command mode by pressing :. I want to then execute the lua function to get the resulting string in command mode. The result would be: I am in command mode with this written: :THE_STRING (note the difference between GET_STRING and THE_STRING)

To do this one can use the expression register: https://neovim.io/doc/user/insert.html#i_CTRL-R_%3D.
Typing :<c-r>=GET_STRING()<cr> results in :THE_STRING.
This calls a vimscript function though. Not sure if it can be done with a lua function.
